# PHP Slim framework instantiating a class

Tags: php, class, instantiation, slim

Ok guys, this must be a noob question but I am having trouble understanding this odd behavior of Slim class instantiation. To be very precise:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

I believe everything is straightforward. Except I cannot understand why I have to write this:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

as opposed to this:

```
$app = new Slim();
```

it's the same when I am referring to a function. This works:

```
  $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

But this doesn't:

```
  $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
```

I believe I have done this quite a few times in the past successfully. It took me like two hours to figure this out. Am I imagining me being able to instantiate classes without including the relative path?

Comment: Check out PHP namespaces documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Pop `use Slim\Slim;` at the top of your script

Comment: Dammit, thanks guys, completely forgot about namespaces!